# What is the scope of effort for making standard java-mode syntax highlighting language release dependent?

Tags: java, emacs, syntax-highlighting

My itch to see the Emacs syntax highlighting handle generics more effectively is getting worse and worse with each new release of the Java language.  I suspect adding customization support for the language level is a significant piece of programming effort.  But it would still be interesting to hear someone knowledgeable expound at a fairly high level on what needs to be done to `cc-mode.el` and or `cc-cmds.el` to make this happen.  Perhaps there is another solution.  Is JDE language level aware?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Quick solution:

```
M-x c++-mode
```

Java generics are similar enough to C++ templates to improve the highlighting of generic variable declarations.  More information on permanent integration seems to be discussed here:
http://osdir.com/ml/emacs.jdee/2007-07/msg00022.html